# Call to a member function getPaginate() on a non-object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, phpstorm

I'm new to laravel framwork , and I'm coding my first web app

and getting the following error

```
 FatalErrorException in PersonController.php line 26:
Call to a member function getPaginate() on a non-object
```

this is my Controller

```
   <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers; 
use App\Repositories\PersonRepository;

class PersonController extends Controller
{
    protected  $personRepo ;
    protected  $nbrPerPage = 4 ;


    public  function  _construct(PersonRepository $personRepository)
    {
        $this->personRepo = $personRepository ;
    }
    public function index()
    {
        $persons = $this->personRepo->getPaginate(nbrPerPage);
        $links = $persons->setPath('')->render();

        return view('index', compact('persons', 'links'));
    }

    public function create()
    {

    }


    public function store()
    {

    }


    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }


    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }


    public function update($id)
    {
        //
    }


    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }


}
```

and this my repository class

```
<?php
namespace  App\Repositories ;
use App\Person ;
use App\User;


class PersonRepository {

  protected  $person ;
    public function  _construct (Person $person)
    {
        $this->$person = $person  ;
    }


    public  function  getPaginate($n)
    {

        return $this->person-> paginate($n) ;
    }


 }
```

Comment: dont know about  laravel  but whats paginate()  ?

Comment: How are you injecting `Person` into your `PersonRepository`?

Comment: @MarkDavidson i think laravel is responsible of this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless these are just typos in the question, you have a lot of typos in your code.

The typo that is causing this specific error is that the name of the constructor method should be `__construct` (with two underscores), not `_construct` (with one underscore).

Since the constructor method is misspelled on your `PersonController`, this method is never called and the `personRepo` attribute is never set. Since it is never set, the line `$persons = $this->personRepo->getPaginate(nbrPerPage);` is trying to call `getPaginate()` on a non-object.

Additional typos/issues I see at a glance:

- `$persons = $this->personRepo->getPaginate(nbrPerPage);`
  `nbrPerPage` is being used as a constant. This is incorrect. Should be:
  `$persons = $this->personRepo->getPaginate($this->nbrPerPage);`
- Constructor on PersonRepository also misspelled. Should be `__construct()`, not `_construct`.
- `$this->$person = $person  ;`
  This is inside the attempted construct of the PersonRepository. The `$` needs to be removed from `$this->$person`. Should be:
  `$this->person = $person;`

Answer (score 3):

You are instantiating an empty instance of the `Person` model and then trying to call `paginate()` on it in your repository. However, [paginate()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/pagination) is meant to be called on either a query builder object or an Eloquent query. Assuming that you want to return paginated results of *all* your models, you can scrap the `$person` property entirely as well as the constructor and then just change your method to this:

```
public  function  getPaginate($n)
{
    return Person::paginate($n) ;
}
```

I will say that for such a simple query, I would suggest not using a repository altogether and just use `Person::paginate($n)` inside your controller, as Eloquent essentially functions as a repository already.